# ioredis_1.Cluster is not a constructor. Jest tests failing after ioredis upgrade

Tags: jestjs, ioredis

I've just upgraded ioredis from v4 to v5.2.4  `"ioredis": "5.2.4"`
I've uninstalled `@types/ioredis`
And have followed the import instructions described here: https://github.com/luin/ioredis/wiki/Upgrading-from-v4-to-v5

Running typescript:
`"typescript": "5.1.3"`

My app runs and builds, but the Jest tests are failing with:
`ioredis_1.Cluster is not a constructor`

I have an init function for Redis:

`isClusterMode` will be false.

```
if (isClusterMode) {
  client = new Cluster(nodes, clusterOptions); // this is the failing line
} else {
  client = new Redis(nodes[0], redisOptions);
}
return client
```

And my test files are setup like:

```
import Redis, { Cluster } from 'ioredis';
jest.mock('ioredis');
...
beforeEach(() => {
  get = jest.spyOn(Redis.prototype, 'get');
  setex = jest.spyOn(Redis.prototype, 'setex');
  del = jest.spyOn(Redis.prototype, 'del');
  addKey = jest.spyOn(Redis.prototype, 'sadd');
  removeKey = jest.spyOn(Redis.prototype, 'srem');
});
```

I think I'm importing everything correctly, but not sure where to go from here.
I've down graded my typescript version and this does not fix the problem.